# How can I use the value of the body outside this method?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, request

```
var request = require('request');

var boardsCall = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/xxxxxxxxxx/boards?filter=open&fields=id,name',
  qs: {
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
};

function test(url, callback) {
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }
    callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
  })
}
const x = test(boardsCall, function(err, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    return body;
  }
})

console.log(x);
```

how can I use the value of the body outside?
to use it in other methods later
I am open to any changes best practices, I read a lot and got a bit confused on the topic of callbacks, promises async await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my approach request is wrapped with `Promise`, test function returns Promise response. Inside the main method test function will be executed synchronously. Once the response value assigned to x do remaining processing logic inside the `main()` method.

```
var request = require('request');

var boardsCall = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/xxxxxxxxxx/boards?filter=open&fields=id,name',
  qs: {
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
};

function test(url) {
    //Wrapping request callback with Promise
    return new Promise((res, rej)=> {
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
              rej(error);
            }
            res(JSON.parse(body));
          })
    })
}

async function main() {
    try {
        const x = await test(boardsCall);       
        console.log("Result : ", x );

        // Remaining logic to process based on x value

    } catch(e) {
        console.error("Error :", e);
    }


}

//Calling main method
main()
```